# Tinyint not as Boolean

Tags: scalikejdbc

I have an existing mysql database which I want to query with scalikejdbc.
The database uses a nullable tinyint for small values in the range [-1,3].

How can I query this value? The only way that seems to work is treating it as a boolean which does not reflect all the values.

```
sql"SELECT * FROM table"
    .map(rs => rs.nullableBoolean("value"))).list().apply
```

If I try to treat it as byte or int or I get a Runtime Exception

```
[ResultSetExtractorException: Failed to retrieve value because For input string: "true". If you're using SQLInterpolation, you may mistake u.id for u.resultName.id.]
```

Comment: The workaround i found is using the underlying resultset. rs.underlying.getInt("value")